# How to update navigation URI of a secondary tile in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1.1

I have an app that can create secondary tiles on start screen based on user's choice.
The secondary tile opens up a document. there is one requirement that whenever the document is renamed, the tile associated with it (if exist), its navigation uri must also be updated so that secondary tile always points to same document.

But i am not able to do this. Only way I see is to delete and recreate the tile. which actually not useful (because it navigates to start screen). i just want to do it internally. However, `ShellTile.Update` method seems no useful to me.

Kindly help.
Any help will be highly appreciated.
Thanx in advance

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a navigation URL to direct the user to the document, use an unique ID that doesn't change when the document is renamed. That way, no matter what happens to the name of the document, the tile will point to where it should.

Comment: i thought of doing it earlier, but then this logic will add on an additional burden of finding the doc from isoStorage/database which will eventually decrease app's performance

Comment: That's the price you pay for being able to keep the live tiles pointed to the correct documents.